# Improper slicing of data Python

Tags: python

The below code is not slicing the data as per my requirement.

```
 import requests
 from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
 from urllib.parse import urljoin
 import re
 import pandas as pd
 import json

 url_list=[]
 url = "https://www.sfma.org.sg/member/category/"
 page = "https://www.sfma.org.sg/member"
 text = requests.get(url).text
 d = re.findall(r'var\s*cObject\s*=\s*(.*)\s*;', text)[0]
 d = re.sub(r'(\w+)(?=:)', r'"\1"', d)
 d = json.loads(d.replace("'", '"'))
 for c in d['category']:
     AC = [c['permalink']]
     urls = [url+m for m in AC]
     print(urls[0:5])
```

It Produces the below output, having all elements in square brackets & no commas between them. Is that the reason for not slicing the data as per the requirement :-

```
   ['https://www.sfma.org.sg/member/category/alcoholic-beverage']
   ['https://www.sfma.org.sg/member/category/beer']
   ['https://www.sfma.org.sg/member/category/bottled-beverage']
   ['https://www.sfma.org.sg/member/category/canned-beverage']
   ['https://www.sfma.org.sg/member/category/carbonated-beverage']
   ['https://www.sfma.org.sg/member/category/cereal-grain-beverage']
   ['https://www.sfma.org.sg/member/category/cider']
   ['https://www.sfma.org.sg/member/category/coffee']
   ['https://www.sfma.org.sg/member/category/distilled-water']
   ['https://www.sfma.org.sg/member/category/fruit-vegetable-juice']
   ['https://www.sfma.org.sg/member/category/herbal-beverage']
   ['https://www.sfma.org.sg/member/category/instant-beverage']
```

The desired output is

```
['https://www.sfma.org.sg/member/category/alcoholic-beverage', 
   'https://www.sfma.org.sg/member/category/beer',
   'https://www.sfma.org.sg/member/category/bottled-beverage',
   'https://www.sfma.org.sg/member/category/canned-beverage']
```

Comment: You never actually add anything to the url_list, just create a bunch of single-element lists AC (and therefore urls).

Comment: You don't need `urls[0:5]`. `urls[:5]` will do the same.

Comment: Your code imports unnecessary libraries and do unobvious things. Provide **minimal** working example and please rephrase your question so we would know, **why** or **how** desired output should be produced.

Answer (score 0):

That is because you are creating a new list every Time and not appending to the outside scope of the for loop. Try something like this.

```
url_list=[]
for c in d['category']:
    # process  result
    url_list.append(result)
print(url_list)
```

Comment: url_list is outside the scope of the loop but not a global variable. Would suggest correcting the same

Answer (score -1):

This is because `urls` is list with a single element and you keep creating a new one every time. **You need to append the `urls` to a list and then print it outside the for loop**.
The code you are looking for is :

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from urllib.parse import urljoin
import re
import pandas as pd
import json

url_list=[]
url = "https://www.sfma.org.sg/member/category/"
page = "https://www.sfma.org.sg/member"
text = requests.get(url).text
d = re.findall(r'var\s*cObject\s*=\s*(.*)\s*;', text)[0]
d = re.sub(r'(\w+)(?=:)', r'"\1"', d)
d = json.loads(d.replace("'", '"'))
for c in d['category']:
    AC = [c['permalink']]
    # notice how I am using urls as a string instead of a list in your case
    urls = url+AC[0] #assuming AC is a list with just 1 element each time
    url_list.append(urls) #see how the element is being added to a common list each time
print(url_list[0:5])
```

The output in the case is :

```
['https://www.sfma.org.sg/member/category/alcoholic-beverage', 'https://www.sfma.org.sg/member/category/beer', 'https://www.sfma.org.sg/member/category/bottled-beverage', 'https://www.sfma.org.sg/member/category/canned-beverage', 'https://www.sfma.org.sg/member/category/carbonated-beverage']
```